# VS compiling successfully when obvious errors exist after upgrading to framework 4.6.1

Tags: roslyn, c#-6.0, build-error, .net-4.6.1

After upgrading my .net web project to use Framework 4.6.1 so that I can take advantage of c#6, I have experienced a problem building projects..

I say I have a 'problem' building, it's more like I don't have a problem building. **It IS building successfully when in fact it should be failing!** Take a look at the screenshot provided; web.config on the left, obvious syntax errors on the right, and a successful build below.

It builds successfully when I do a build / rebuild or run it in debugging; but does actually fail if I try to perform a publish.

Just to further, I have verified that the file that I am editing resides in the correct directory within App_Code, that I am building the correct project and have reset VS multiple times. I've tried to go through all school boy errors; but I think that as it successfully runs but throws a compilation error at that stage it is something down to the Roslyn compiler?

Also note, this is a freshly created project; All I have done is written some basic classes, upgraded the framework, and added a blank aspx page.

[image: Project building with syntax errors]

Comment: Dumb question but... have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: @Dunning-Kruger Yep -> 'have reset VS multiple times'

Answer (score -2):

Recreating the solution *file* fixed this error.

Another cause could be down to the fact that I created the project as a WebApplication instead of a Website, but am unsure why this would cause successful builds with syntax errors.

Regenerating the solution with the project setup as a Website instead of a WebAppplication fixed the issue (although I had to change front-end control attributes 'CodeBehind' to 'CodeFile'; a difference between the two types of project).

Comment: Not quite sure why I'm getting downvoted? No one came up with a suggestion for this legitimate problem, had to solve it myself, and posted the answer. By keeping this question up my hope is that anyone experiencing this issue can quickly solve it by rebuilding the solution. If anyone has any other ideas of the cause they are welcome to post a better answer.